# .com/ vs .com when hosting a website

Tags: web-development, 404

I used a free domain hosting service with their extension suffixed to my website. When I tried to look at the site on a browser, I get a 404 error unless I add a / at the end of .com suffix (or) explicitly hardcode .com/index.html the site shows a 404 error.

Why is my website giving a 404 error? Should I do a mapping or something special to make it look at the index.html file in the public_html folder by default?

I used FireFTP to upload the HTML, CSS, JS and jQuery files to the domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some hostings might not have mapping for default file to be used as homepage, thus you might sometimes need to add it.

If this is Apache-based hosting(commonly Linux hostings use Apache), you will want to create/add new line to `.htaccess` file like so:

**.htaccess file:**

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

If it's Windows-based hosting running IIS, check how to set default directory index [here](http://www.dantor.com/support/misc/web-config-default-website-document.aspx).

**web.config file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">    <!-- this line enables default documents for a directory -->
         <files>      
            <clear/>     <!-- removes the existing default document list -->                
            <add value="foo.htm"/>     <!-- foo.htm is now the default document  -->                
            <add value="foo.php"/>     <!-- 2nd default document in search order -->                
            <add value="foo.aspx/>     <!-- 3rd default document in search order -->                
            <add value="foo.cfm/>      <!-- 4th default document in search order -->
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: wrong: `.htaccess` is not for *Linux* hosting, it is for *Linux* hosting with *Apache*. [lighttpd](http://lighttpd.net/) is a web server running on Linux and does not use `.htaccess`

Comment: Corrected -----

Comment: Correction: `it is for hosting with Apache.`. The same applies to Apache running under Windows.